# Fluent Migrator waiting for user input in azure/kudu

Tags: azure, deployment, kudu, fluent-migrator

I am trying to use fluent migrator for database deployments inside of azure/kudu.  I am calling the Migrate.exe from the deployment command.  When running in azure/kudu the migrations run successfully and then wait for user input.  Obviously there is no user input and the deployment throws a timeout error.  The exact error is:

```
Command 'starter.cmd deploy.cmd' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 61 seconds.
```

When I run the same Migrate.exe locally it runs and then returns to the command prompt without waiting for user input.

Any ideas why inside of Azure/kudu a script would wait for user input and locally it wouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was calling the powershell script incorrectly.

Previously the old (not working) deployment command got call like this: call :ExecuteCmd PowerShell -Version 2.0 ".\Deploy.ps1"
And I changed it to: call :ExecuteCmd PowerShell ".\Deploy.ps1"

I just removed the hard coded "-Version 2.0" and everything ran successful.

So if you are calling a powershell script with version 2.0 hard coded and are getting some odd errors you should remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. 
The sandbox itself runs in a Job controlled by the Azure Web App administrative service (the moral equivalent of WAS service in Windows). A process within the sandbox can create its own nested Job for child processes to occupy. You may take a look at the Sandbox restrictions here: General Sandbox Restrictions: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions

Azure Load Balancer has a default idle timeout setting of four minutes. This is generally a reasonable response time limit for a web request. If your web app requires background processing, we recommend using Azure WebJobs. The Azure web app can call WebJobs and be notified when background processing is finished. You can choose from multiple methods for using WebJobs, including queues and triggers.
WebJobs is designed for background processing. You can do as much background processing as you want in a WebJob.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  This was helpful but it didn't turn out to be my issue.